# No module named 'distutils.command.bdist_msi'

Tags: python, distutils, pycurl

In Pycharm (Windows 11) I set up a basic project consisting of one line:

```
import pycurl
```

The environment is Virtualenv, the base intepreter path is `C:\Users\strat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python311\python.exe`

Of course, since the module is not installed, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\strat\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\main.py", line 6, in <module>
    import pycurl
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pycurl'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

So I try to install it, the way I generally do in Linux:

```
pip install pycurl
```

but I get:

```
  Collecting pycurl
  Using cached pycurl-7.45.1.tar.gz (233 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [9 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\strat\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7dqnopvz\pycurl_f564efcc68fa4b198200e92ae58e8c8b\setup.py", line 954, in <module>
          setup_args['cmdclass'] = {'bdist_msi': get_bdist_msi_version_hack()}
                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\strat\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7dqnopvz\pycurl_f564efcc68fa4b198200e92ae58e8c8b\setup.py", line 594, in get_bdist_msi_version_hack      
          from distutils.command.bdist_msi import bdist_msi
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.command.bdist_msi'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

What's the origin of this error? [As far as I understand](https://docs.python.org/3/library/distutils.html) they are about to remove `distutils` after its deprecation, but, as a simple user of a library, what can I do?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. My solution was:

- I downloaded and installed exe file: https://pypi.org/project/pycurl/7.43.0.5/#files
- In my virtual environment in file pyvenv.cfg i set "include-system-site-packages = true"
- Deactivate and again activate virtual environment.